# C# Overwrite string and string[] in another Function

Tags: c#, arrays, string, function

I overwrite the variables 'arr[1]' and 'test' in setValues() function.

arr[1] is changed to 'BBB'

but test doesn't change to '222'

> Output: BBB111

but it should be BBB222

Why string test doesn't get updated?

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[10];

            arr[1] = "AAA";
            string test = "111";

            setValues(arr, test);

            int exit = -1;
            while (exit < 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arr[i]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + test);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void setValues(string[] arr, string test)
        {
            arr[1] = "BBB";
            test = "222";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Furthermore to add to the answers below, String objects are immutable: they cannot be changed after they have been created. All of the String methods and C# operators that appear to modify a string actually return the results in a new string object.

Comment: I recommend you read [Parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) by Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass that string by reference to be able to modify it in a method, you can do this by adding the `ref` keyword:

```
public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[10];

            arr[1] = "AAA";
            string test = "111";

            setValues(arr, ref test);

            int exit = -1;
            while (exit < 0)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(arr[i]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(arr[i] + test);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private static void setValues(string[] arr, ref string test)
        {
            arr[1] = "BBB";
            test = "222";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to call the method with `ref` as well.

Comment: Why does string test need that "ref" while string[] arr doesn't?

Comment: @Chelayos Because with string[] you are passing the reference to the array, which you are not modifying. What you are modifying is the contents of the array, not the pointer to the array itself.  You can test this by setting arr = new string[0] inside of setValues and this change will not propogate to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

You are only altering the local reference to `test` in your `setValues` function.  You would need to pass this variable by reference (`ref`)

```
private static void setValues(string[] arr, ref string test)
{
    arr[1] = "BBB";
    test = "222";
}
```

then call it like this:

```
setValues(arr, ref test);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `test` prameter in the `setValues` method is not marked as `ref` so it is changed only inside the method and the value does not get outside.

Answer (score 0):

Because the array as object is passed by reference while the string is passed by value.
So, the function setValues() update the local copy of test, invisible to the caller, while update the ONLY instance of string[] arr, visible either to the caller than to the callee.

Paolo

Comment: Both are passed as values.  Specifically the values passed are references to the objects.  Note that `arr = new string[0];` in the method would not have updated the variable passed into the method.  The difference is that the array's contents are updated, while the copy of the reference to the string is updated.

Comment: @juharr: what I mean is, as stated in the link you posted  [...] To reiterate: class types, interface types, delegate types and array types are all reference types. [...]. So, if I understand, array is passed as reference because is a reference type.

Comment: No, it's still passed as a value, it's just that the value passed is a reference.  The distinction in the link I posted is that the array is a reference type, but the parameter type it is passed as is value.  Here's a direct quote about that _I believe it is highly confusing to say that objects are passed by reference by default instead of the correct statement that object references are passed by value by default_

Comment: And even if it were true that the type of a variable determined how it was passed then you also have to realize that `string` is a reference type and not a value type (the fact that it's immutable and has a lower case alias does make that fact less than obvious).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is variable scope.  The variables referenced in your SetValues() method aren't the same variables referenced in Main.
There are 2 ways to resolve this, based on the need of the class:

1. As stated in other answers, pass the values by reference in the SetValues method (this preserves your code as-is):

> ```
> private static void setValues(string[] arr, ref string test)
> {
>     arr[1] = "BBB";
>     test = "222";
> }
> ```

2. Move the variable declaration outside of the body of Main (This changes the scope of the variables to Class-level variables, which scopes them to the entire class, and possibly allows accessing them from other classes):

> ```
> public class Program
>     {
>         static string[] arr = new string[10];
>         static string test = "111";
>
>         static void Main(string[] args)
>         {
>             arr[1] = "AAA";
> ```
>
> and then call it by reference as well:
>
> `SetValues(arr, ref test);`

Comment: In this situation, scope is not the problem since you are passing the variable to the method, it has everything to do with not calling it by reference.

Comment: Plus, the declaration you have of `arr` and `test` are *instance* variables of `Program`, while `Main` is `static`, so `arr` and `test` are not available (without a `new Program` somewhere to be able to use them).

Comment: Correct.  I should have reversed my examples and expanded a bit more about moving them outside the declaration, but both are valid ways of answering the question based on the need of the class.  Since this is a basic (but very good) question, and the user has low reputation on the site, I felt it necessary to provide more information than just the standard answers that everyone else is giving.

Comment: @crashmstr - Thank you for pointing that out, I was so focused on my explanations that I missed the obvious.  I have corrected that.